# How to give double space between every three lines in a text file using awk?

Tags: awk

How can I give double space between every three lines in a text file using awk?

### Sample input:

```
line1
line2
line3     
line4
line5
line6
line7
----
----
```

### Sample output:

```
line1
line2
line3

line4
line5
line6

line7
----
----
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: I can give you a hint, but the rest should be up to you :) `.*?\n.*?\n.*?\n` will give you three lines. now you only have to add another newline.

Comment: @twall: That won't work in AWK.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i had sed in mind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk 'NR % 3 == 0 { print $0 ; print "" } NR % 3' INPUTFILE
```

And there are other ways...

Comment: The `!= 0` and the `{ print $0 }` can be removed to shorten the command, as they are both implicit by default, which leaves `awk 'NR % 3 == 0 { print $0 ; print "" } NR % 3'`

Comment: @Balint: This is a little shorter: `awk '{print} !(NR % 3) {print ""}' inputfile`